# Sending email from website using Gmail SMTP server through PHP Mailer

Tags: php, email, ssl

I am trying to send an email from my website using Gmail SMTP server through PHP Mailer,unfortunately it not sending its not showing anything like on processForm.php  ErrorInfo or Message has been sent ,below is my code can any one tell me why its not working

processForm.php

```
<?php

print "hi";



include "class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class file name
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "xxxxxxxxx6@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("arokxavi16@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("arokiaxavierraja16@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send())
    {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Message has been sent";
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

use this instead of ssl it may work.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.googlemail.com";
```

instead of

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Another solution is also here. without using class.phpmailer.php

```
    $to = 'arokiaxavierraja16@gmail.com';

    $from =  'xxxxxx@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Test';      
    $msg = 'hello';
    $headers = "From:". $from;
    $message = "Hello";

    if(!mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) { 
       echo 'Error'; 
    } 
    else {
      echo "Success";
    }
```

Comment: OP is using phpmailer already – so your “answer” does not add anything new here, or anything that pertains to the actual problem. Please answer a question only if you have an _actual_ answer to the problem at hand, but not just for the sake of answering something.

Comment: In my case including/using only class.phpmailer.php without whole PHPMailer it was not working. So i use this way and worked fine. So you can not vote down to me.  @Xavi please try this way and let me know it's working or not.

Comment: @herr mail() don't have authentication. So, recipient will get email with diff headers and may get it in the Junk folder.